# Orange suited guy in Phantom Menace on Tatooine

Tags: star-wars, character-identification, the-phantom-menace

I rewatched *Phantom Menace* last night, and this character really jumped out at me. He has 2 full seconds to himself alone on screen.

He is a skull faced guy in an orange (space?) suit with an orange motorcycle/space helmet. He is walking the streets of Mos Espa.

He appears in the scene immediately before the start of the Pod Race. It was the scene where we see Darth Maul's dark eye probe droids surveilling the area.

Do we know anything about this guy? A name? A race? Does his mode of dress indicates he is a member of some group? Out of universe, perhaps his appearance is a reference to something in our world?

[image: orange suited background character of Tatooine]

I tried searching the Internet for phrases like "orange skull face guy phantom menace" but came up with nothing. On this site, I also filtered a few questions tagged "phantom-menace" but found nothing either.

Comment: @Gallifreian Why would people complain in the comments to every question about anything other than the original trilogy? Prequel jokes have gotten really old, as did other ones about anything the fans don't like, which is a huge list by now. Frankly, I even think that Star Wars fans are more united in what they hate rather than what they like.

Comment: @Malcolm, I'm sorry I've made a bad impression - my comment was intended as a joke, and this particular joke had become somewhat of  meme (at least among me and my friends). I don't hate prequels or EU, I just honestly don't think TPM is worth watching more than one time - it doesn't give the same feeling as other films (I'm a fan of the Revenge of the Sith though)

Comment: @Gallifreian I spoke more in general rather than to you personally. It's just I see complaints about prequels, George Lucas, Jar-Jar, midichlorians, retcons - virtually anything after 1983 - _so often_ that I wonder why these people even still call themselves Star Wars fans. There are many people who enjoy other stuff than the original trilogy, so let's agree to disagree and leave each other be.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In Legends, he's a bounty hunter named [Rum Sleg](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Rum_Sleg). He was identified as such in assorted film merchandise, such as this Topps trading card:

[image]

The reverse of the card reads:

> A male humanoid bounty hunter, Rum Sleg is present at Mos Espa around the time of the Boonta Eve Classic podrace in 32 BBY. Although his skills are clearly demonstrated in high-speed contests such as this, the true identity of Rum Sleg remains unknown. The skull-like face set in his helmet is merely for dramatic ornamentation, and does not represent Sleg's true facial appearance. He could be a representative of any of the thousands of humanoid species in the galaxy.

As far as I know, he's yet to be introduced in any canon properties. However, Leland Chee is on record as not caring to change the details of minor background characters needlessly, so presumably Sleg remains canon until contradicted.

Comment: In the comic, Survivors, an individual similar in appearance to Rum Sleg (possibly Sleg himself) was killed by Uda-Khalid, and was visible among the crowd of Uda-Khalid's victims (c)wookipedia